# Emacs Lisp: how to avoid inserting a duplicate list item?

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do I check if a string is already in a list in Emacs Lisp? I need to check if a certain path string is already in `exec-path`, and then add it to that list if it's not.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The function [`add-to-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html#index-add_002dto_002dlist-391) will check automatically before adding

```
(setq a '(1 2 3))
(add-to-list 'a 4)
(add-to-list 'a 3)
```

will result in `a` equal to (4 1 2 3)

From Emacs 26 <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `add-to-list`:

```
(add-to-list LIST-VAR ELEMENT &optional APPEND COMPARE-FN)

Add ELEMENT to the value of LIST-VAR if it isn’t there yet.
The test for presence of ELEMENT is done with ‘equal’, or with
COMPARE-FN if that’s non-nil.
If ELEMENT is added, it is added at the beginning of the list,
unless the optional argument APPEND is non-nil, in which case
ELEMENT is added at the end.

The return value is the new value of LIST-VAR.

This is handy to add some elements to configuration variables,
but please do not abuse it in Elisp code, where you are usually
better off using ‘push’ or ‘cl-pushnew’.

If you want to use ‘add-to-list’ on a variable that is not
defined until a certain package is loaded, you should put the
call to ‘add-to-list’ into a hook function that will be run only
after loading the package.  ‘eval-after-load’ provides one way to
do this.  In some cases other hooks, such as major mode hooks,
can do the job.
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [cobbal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73681/cobbal) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896570/emacs-lisp-how-to-avoid-inserting-a-duplicate-list-item/896582#896582) about [`add-to-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html#index-add_002dto_002dlist-391), there's also [`cl-pushnew`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/cl.html#index-cl_002dpushnew-21):

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(setq list-of-strings '("one" "two" "three"))
(cl-pushnew "two" list-of-strings :test #'string=)
    ⇒ ("one" "two" "three")
(cl-pushnew "zero" list-of-strings :test #'string=)
    ⇒ ("zero" "one" "two" "three")
```

The [`:test`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/cl.html#Sequence-Basics) [`#'string=`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Comparison.html#Text-Comparison) argument is needed in your case because, `cl-pushnew` uses [`eql`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Comparison-of-Numbers.html#index-eql-172) to compare by default, and it doesn't treat two strings with the same content as equal. ([`equal`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Equality-Predicates.html#Equality-Predicates)) would work too.

```el
(eql "some-string" "some-string")
    ⇒ nil
(string= "some-string" "some-string")
    ⇒ t
(equal "some-string" "some-string")
    ⇒ t
```

From Emacs 26 <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `cl-pushnew`:

```
cl-pushnew is a Lisp macro in ‘cl-lib.el’.

(cl-pushnew X PLACE [KEYWORD VALUE]...)

(cl-pushnew X PLACE): insert X at the head of the list if not already there.
Like (push X PLACE), except that the list is unmodified if X is ‘eql’ to
an element already on the list.

Keywords supported:  :test :test-not :key
```